# Perl6: How to load a class module dynamically?

Tags: oop, module, raku

How can I load a OO-style module dynamically?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;

my $r = prompt ':';

if $r {
    require Text::CSV;          # Error:
    my $csv = Text::CSV.new;    # Could not find symbol '&CSV'
} else {
    require File::Temp <&tempfile>;
    my ( $filename , $filehandle ) = tempfile; # this works
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in the perl6 doco [here](https://doc.perl6.org/language/modules#require), you can dynamically load the module but;

> To import symbols you must define them at compile time.

So, the code in the `else` clause works because of the explicit request to import `<&tempfile>`.

The closest thing to getting the code in the `if` clause to work that I can see is this (which is mostly taken from that earlier doco reference):

```
use v6.c ;

sub load-a-module($name) {
   require ::($name) ;
   my $instance = ::($name).new() ;
   return $instance ;
}

my $module = "Text::CSV" ;
my $csv = load-a-module $module ;
say $csv.WHAT ;
# say $csv.^methods ;   # if you really want to be convinced

# outputs: (CSV)
```